# In bash, how do I pass the while loops input to the cut command?

Tags: linux, bash, cut

How do I pass the $line to the cut command properly in this loop?

```
while read line
do
    login= $(cut -d : -f 1)

done < /etc/passwd
```

I can't do `$(cut -d : -f 1 $line)` so what is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need the while loop if your intention is only to list the names. Also there is a syntax error after `login=`, there should be no space.

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | \
while read login; 
do 
    echo username: $login;
done
```

or as you tried:

```
while read line; do
   login=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 1)
   echo $login
done < /etc/passwd
```

even better:

```
db-getent passwd |cut -d: -f1 | xargs -L1 echo name:
```

Comment: +1 for `getent`. In your first example, line continuations are not required after a pipe.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Ярослав, the loop was a snippet of code from a larger while loop so your second suggestion is perfect for me.

Answer (score 3):

Let the `read` command together with the shell `IFS` variable parse the line for you:

```
while IFS=: read -r login restOfLine; do
    doSomethingWith $login
done < /etc/passwd
```

To answer your question, the bash here-string would be useful:

```
login=$(cut -d: -f1 <<< "$line")
```

Comment: The here-string is nice and tidy I like that! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use *echo*:

```
login=$(echo "$line" | cut -d : -f 1)
```